# Flatten multiple names arrays within variant json column in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have a web scraper dumping data into a variant column in a Snowflake database.
This is acraping page data as then creates json arrays for various tables found within the page.

Here is an example of the type of json i would find using a Soccer analogy:

```
    {
  "dom_url": "https://www.soccertables.com/european_tables",
  "event_id": "01b2722a-d8e6-4f67-95d0-8dd7ba088a4a",
  "event_utc_time": "2020-05-11 09:01:14.821",
  "ip_address": "125.238.134.96",
  "table_1": [
    {
      "position": "1",
      "team_name": "Liverpool",
      "games_played": "29",
      "games_won": "26",
      "games_drawn": "2",
      "games_lost": "1",
      "goals_for": "75",
      "goals_against": "35"
      "points": "80"
    },
    {
      "position": "2",
      "team_name": "Man. City",
      "games_played": "29",
      "games_won": "20",
      "games_drawn": "5",
      "games_lost": "4",
      "goals_for": "60",
      "goals_against": "45"
      "points": "65"
    },
    {
      "position": "...",
      "team_name": "...",
      "games_played": "...",
      "games_won": "...",
      "games_drawn": "...",
      "games_lost": "...",
      "goals_for": "...",
      "goals_against": "..."
      "points": "..."
    }
  ],
  "table_2": [
    {
      "position": "1",
      "team_name": "Bayern Munich",
      "games_played": "29",
      "games_won": "26",
      "games_drawn": "2",
      "games_lost": "1",
      "goals_for": "75",
      "goals_against": "35"
      "points": "80"
    },
    {
      "position": "2",
      "team_name": "Bayer Leverkussen",
      "games_played": "29",
      "games_won": "20",
      "games_drawn": "5",
      "games_lost": "4",
      "goals_for": "60",
      "goals_against": "45"
      "points": "65"
    },
    {
      "position": "...",
      "team_name": "...",
      "games_played": "...",
      "games_won": "...",
      "games_drawn": "...",
      "games_lost": "...",
      "goals_for": "...",
      "goals_against": "..."
      "points": "..."
    }
  ],
  "referrer_url": "https://www.soccertables.com",
}
```

Ideally, i'd like the output of this to be a flat, relational table:

table_name     position     team_name     games_played     etc...
table_1        1            Liverpool     29               ...
table_1        2            Man. City     29               ...
table_2        1            Bayern Munich 29               ...
....

I know that if i were only interested in table_1 i could do this:

```
SELECT v.value:position::NUMBER POSITION
       , v.value:team_name::STRING TEAM_NAME
       , v.value:games_played::NUMBER GAMES_PLAYED
       , ...
FROM JSON_TABLE a1, LATERAL FLATTEN(JSON_DATA:table_1) v
```

and that i could do the same for table_2 and union them, but there can be N possibilities with regards to the table_N placeholder.

I've looked at doing LATERAL FLATTEN multiple times:

```
SELECT v.value:position::NUMBER POSITION
       , v.value:team_name::STRING TEAM_NAME
       , v.value:games_played::NUMBER GAMES_PLAYED
       , ...
FROM JSON_TABLE a1, LATERAL FLATTEN(JSON_DATA:table_1) v, LATERAL FLATTEN(JSON_DATA:table_2) v2
```

But this results in duplication of data, and does not allow me to put each tables columns all in a single relational structure.

I'm sure there is something simple that i am missing here, but i've reached a point where i think i've been staring at this too long, and just can';t see it.

Thanks in advance,
S

Comment: does each table have the same elements and you are simply trying to flatten them all out into the same view/table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a single, flattened view of the table_n data, as well as the attributes of at the first level, then something like this would work.

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT '{
  "dom_url": "https://www.soccertables.com/european_tables",
  "event_id": "01b2722a-d8e6-4f67-95d0-8dd7ba088a4a",
  "event_utc_time": "2020-05-11 09:01:14.821",
  "ip_address": "125.238.134.96",
  "table_1": [
    {
      "position": "1",
      "team_name": "Liverpool",
      "games_played": "29",
      "games_won": "26",
      "games_drawn": "2",
      "games_lost": "1",
      "goals_for": "75",
      "goals_against": "35",
      "points": "80"
    },
    {
      "position": "2",
      "team_name": "Man. City",
      "games_played": "29",
      "games_won": "20",
      "games_drawn": "5",
      "games_lost": "4",
      "goals_for": "60",
      "goals_against": "45",
      "points": "65"
    },
    {
      "position": "...",
      "team_name": "...",
      "games_played": "...",
      "games_won": "...",
      "games_drawn": "...",
      "games_lost": "...",
      "goals_for": "...",
      "goals_against": "...",
      "points": "..."
    }
  ],
  "table_2": [
    {
      "position": "1",
      "team_name": "Bayern Munich",
      "games_played": "29",
      "games_won": "26",
      "games_drawn": "2",
      "games_lost": "1",
      "goals_for": "75",
      "goals_against": "35",
      "points": "80"
    },
    {
      "position": "2",
      "team_name": "Bayer Leverkussen",
      "games_played": "29",
      "games_won": "20",
      "games_drawn": "5",
      "games_lost": "4",
      "goals_for": "60",
      "goals_against": "45",
      "points": "65"
    },
    {
      "position": "...",
      "team_name": "...",
      "games_played": "...",
      "games_won": "...",
      "games_drawn": "...",
      "games_lost": "...",
      "goals_for": "...",
      "goals_against": "...",
      "points": "..."
    }
  ],
  "referrer_url": "https://www.soccertables.com",
}' as var)
SELECT
  parse_json(x.var):dom_url::string,
  parse_json(x.var):event_id::string,
  parse_json(x.var):event_utc_time::string,
  parse_json(x.var):ip_address::string,
  x3.value:games_drawn::string,
  x3.value:games_lost::string,
  x3.value:games_played::string,
  x3.value:games_won::string,
  x3.value:goals_against::string,
  x3.value:goals_for::string,
  x3.value:points::string,
  x3.value:position::string,
  x3.value:team_name::string
FROM x
,LATERAL FLATTEN(parse_json(x.var)) x2
,LATERAL FLATTEN(X2.VALUE) x3;
```

The CTE is obviously just to show the example with the sample JSON you provided.  If you care about which records came from which table, you can also include `x2.key` as an element in your `SELECT`.

Comment: Mike Walton you are a legend!  Thanks for this